# Show that the boundary of a set equals the boundary of its complement

Tags: general-topology

$\newcommand{\bdy}{\operatorname{bdy}}$

I'm trying to show that $\bdy(A) = \bdy(A^c)$.

I know that $\bdy(A) = \operatorname{closure} A \setminus \operatorname{int}(A) = (\operatorname{int}(A^c))^c \setminus \operatorname{int}(A)$, but I don't know where to go from there.

Any help or hints would be very much appreciated.

Comment: bdy(A^c) = closure A^c \ int(A^c)?

Comment: How do you define closure and int? $\partial A$ is often defined as the set of elements of the ambient space $X$ such that every neighborhood contains elements both of $A$ and $A^c$, and of course this is symmetric in $A$ and $A^c$

Comment: @Cocopuffs Agree, but I don't know how to apply that to this proof.

Comment: @therexists: Cocopuffs asked a question. Please edit your question to answer hir.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you know that $\mathrm{closure}(A)=(\mathrm{int}(A^c))^c$, then you also have  $\mathrm{closure}(A^c)=(\mathrm{int}(A))^c$ because $(A^c)^c=A$.  Therefore

$$\mathrm{boundary}(A)=\mathrm{closure}(A)\cap(\mathrm{int}(A))^c = \mathrm{closure}(A)\cap \mathrm{closure}(A^c).$$

The last expression is symmetric in $A$ and $A^c$.

Comment: Thank you so much. You helped me a lot!

Answer (score 2):

A point in X is said to be a boundary point of a set A if each neighborhood of the point intersects both A and X\A. If you replace A with the complement of A in the statement, you get the same statement. So very simply both the sets have the same boundary.

Comment: This is a question about topological spaces. There are no spheres here.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos:  That's right, but if the word "sphere" is replaced by "set" or better "neighborhood", a cogent Answer results.

Comment: If you edit your explanation to say "neighbourhood" instead of "open sphere", then other people will understand your explanation, and maybe upvote it.

Comment: I thought this question was on metric spaces. Apologies for the confusion!

Answer (score 0):

Note that for a metric space $(X,d)$, and $A \subset X$, $bdy(A)$ is $cl(A) \cap$ $cl(X \backslash A)$. To show that $bd(A)$ is a subset of $bd(X \backslash A)$ (a similar argument can show the reverse inclusion), it really just suffices to show that $X \backslash (X \backslash A)$  is $A$.

Note that an equivalent definition of the boundary of A is
$cl(A) \backslash int(A)$. If you’re using this definition, I suggest you prove that the two definitions are indeed equivalent.

Answer (score -2):

To show that the boundary of a set A is equal to the boundary of it complement , it suffices to show that there exist an element x in between the boundaries of $A$ and $A^c$ . 
So if $x$ belongs to boundary of $A$, 
This implies there exist $y$ and $z$ such that $y$ belongs to $A$ and $z$ belongs to $A^c$ .
This implies bd $(A)=x=bd (A^c)$. Hence $bd (A)=bd(A^c)$ .